# Post request empty response PHP curl

Tags: php

[image: Postman answer]

[image: My answer]

When trying to send a post request to the server, the response returns an empty array "{}". But there is an answer on postsman. Presumably this is related to the content type of the response

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.business.kazanexpress.ru/api/oauth/token? 
grant_type=password&username={}&password={}";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Authorization: Basic token",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Content-Length: 0",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

Comment: Test it with the Postman **Code** section.

Comment: _"Presumably this is related to the content type of the response"_ - I don't see how that could be the case - you are not _treating_ the response any differently, based on that. And it is a _text_ value to begin with - so `var_dump($resp);` can not give you an "empty array" here - if anything, this means that the remote party responded with just the _text_ `{}`. (So presumably a JSON response, containing of nothing but an empty object.)

Comment: `&username={}&password={}` - are you actually trying to send `{}` as the parameter values here, or is this supposed to signal that you left out sensitive values? Depending on what those values actually are, you should probably apply proper URL encoding, because cURL does _not_ do that on its own, when you give it an already assembled URL like this.

Comment: Еhis is done to hide sensitive data

Comment: @A.Seddighi It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Usually the OAuth2 provider will want you to send the data inside the POST body and not in the URL. To do this you can send an array with your `grant_type`, `username` and `password` using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and remove the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers since cURL will generate them for you when using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

It should look something like this

```php
<?php

$url = "https://api.business.kazanexpress.ru/api/oauth/token";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'grant_type' => 'password'
]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
   "Authorization: Basic token",
];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pierrick Charron, I set my username, password and token, but response is empty again

Comment: @Gutufik under the save button in Postman you have a `Code` button where you can export your postman request in different languages/utils. You can export it for PHP does it work this way ? Do you see any difference ?

Comment: i tried that but still no answer @Pierrick